# can't find my error in creating a function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I keep getting an SQL query with the following query:

```
CREATE FUNCTION qualCand(salary int, gpa decimal(5,3), city varchar(255), state char(2)) returns VARCHAR(255)

DECLARE r VARCHAR(255)

SET r = (SELECT ca.firstname, ca.lastname, ca.phone, ca.email 
     FROM Candidates ca 
     JOIN education e
     ON ca.candID = e.candID 
     JOIN desiredPos dPos 
     ON ca.candID = dPos.candID 
     JOIN desiredLocation dLoc 
     ON ca.candID = dloc.candID 
     WHERE dPos.desiredSalary >= salary AND
     dLoc.sity = city AND
     dLoc.state = state AND
     e.GPA >= gpa);
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DECLARE r VARCHAR(255)
>
> SET r = (SELECT ca.firstname, ca.lastname, ca.phone, c' at line 3

Answer (score 1):

There several things wrong with this example.

First of all, you are declaring `r` to be a `VARCHAR` and yet you are trying to assign a result set to it.

Secondly, to set a variable to a column's value from a SELECT query, the syntax would be like this:

`SELECT @r = firstname FROM Table ...`

Here is a link to MySQL documentation to help you better understand the different syntax rules for what you are trying to do: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html